# Can we have one to many relationship in single table by splitting it in EF Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

So basically I have one table which has salaries(id,employee_id,amount,status,start_date)

```
| id  | employee_id | amount | status   | start_date | end_date |
| 1   |     1       |  100   | active   | 2023-12-30 |2024-01-30|
| 2   |     1       |   200  | scheduled| 2024-01-30 |null      |
| 3   |     1       |   50  | scheduled | 2022-01-10 |2023-12-30|
```

It is in different db and it is private
So what I'm trying to do is to split this one table into two different entities
One is gonna be Employee
Another one is Salary

Employee can have several Salaries and only one of them can be active,we also can schedule salary,and salary also can be archived

The problem Im facing is in mapping
When Im trying to cofigure dbContext of it

Ive found a few articles when they just split table into different entries not with relationship

Well,

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Teams.Domain.Aggregates.Salary;

namespace Teams.Infrastructure;

public class TeamsDbPrivateContext : DbContext
{

    public TeamsDbPrivateContext(DbContextOptions<TeamsDbPrivateContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Salary> Salaries { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<Employee> Employee { get; set; } = null!;

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        #region TableSplitting

        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>(
            dob =>
            {
                dob.ToTable("salaries");
                dob.HasKey(o => o.EmployeeId);
                dob.Property(o => o.EmployeeId).HasColumnName("employee_id");

                dob.OwnsMany(b => b.Salaries, salary =>
                {
                    
                    salary.ToTable("salaries"); 
                    salary.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("employee_id");
                    salary.HasKey(s => s.Id);
                    salary.Property(s => s.Id).HasColumnName("id");
                    salary.Property(s => s.Status).HasColumnName("status");
                    salary.Property(s => s.Amount).HasColumnName("amount");
                });
            });
        
        #endregion

    }
}
```

I know that I should configure them in different files)

So my **Employee** looks like this

```
using Teams.Domain.SeedWork;

namespace Teams.Domain.Aggregates.Salary;

public class Employee : Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
    private readonly List<Salary> _salaries = new();
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Salary> Salaries => _salaries;
}
```

This is my ***Salary*** class

```
using Teams.Domain.SeedWork;

namespace Teams.Domain.Aggregates.Salary;

public class Salary : Entity
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public long Amount { get; set; }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/table-splitting

Comment: There's no Employee data in that table. That's a perfectly fine Salary table and entity that has a 1-M relation with an Employee that's not shown in the question at all. There's no reason to split anything. You need to find where the actual `Employee` entity is

Comment: Well project was originially written in php/laravel.
It is in different db,as I said there two dbs.
In the first db we have everything related to employee and other things
But in the second one it is private one,and only a few can acces to it,it has only salary table 
My job is to archive the current Salary of the Employee from the second db create two salary records(the first one should be active in status and second one is scheduled),when an event happens in the first db

Comment: So the *real* question is how to use tables from different databases in EF Core. There are similar questions already and the answer depends on the actual database you use. You can't connect to multiple databases at the same time, so you can't map entities to different databases. In SQL Server though, you can use [CREATE SYNONYM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to make a table from one database appear in another. Another option is to map to a view that includes results from other databases.